# Rename multiple files with text file bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I want to rename my files using a .txt file with proper names These are my files:

```
lesson1.mp4
lesson2.mp4
lesson3.mp4
...
```

This is my txt file with names:

```
1 Entry to vim
2 Basics of vim
3 Vim motion
...
```

The result I want to have is:

```
1 Entry to vim.mp4
2 Basics of vim.mp4
3 Vim motion.mp4
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Read each file into arrays with `readadday`. Then you can loop over the two arrays in parallel, and perform the `mv` commands to rename the files.

Comment: @Barmar: `readarray`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes. I guess I'm typing with an accent. :)

Comment: In some circles it is still a shooting offense to intentionally create filenames with whitespace.  Can't you use `'-'` or `'_'`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

The `file.txt` and its content

```
1 Entry to vim
2 Basic of vim
3 Vim motion
4 Search and Replace
```

---

The `*.mp4` files.

```
lesson1.mp4
lesson2.mp4
lesson3.mp4
lesson4.mp4
```

---

The script.

```
#!/bin/sh

counter=1

while IFS= read -r files; do
  echo mv -v "lesson$counter.mp4" "$files.mp4"
  counter=$((counter+1))
done < file.txt
```

---

Another approach using `bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=1

while [[ -e lesson$counter.mp4 ]]; do
  IFS= read -r files &&
  echo mv -v "lesson$counter.mp4" "$files.mp4"
  ((counter++))
done < file.txt
```

---

Knowing the amount of lessons beforehand, which looks like it is known. Using brace expansion with bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in lesson{1..4}.mp4; do
  IFS= read -r files &&
  echo mv -v "$file" "$files.mp4"
done < file.txt
```

---

- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

---

Output without the `echo`

```
renamed 'lesson1.mp4' -> '1 Entry to vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson2.mp4' -> '2 Basic of vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson3.mp4' -> '3 vim motion.mp4'
renamed 'lesson4.mp4' -> '4 Search and Replace.mp4'
```

---

EDIT:

> This is my txt file with names:

Since it is not clear if the `text` file has the contents of the names or a text file itself with a unique names like the following.

```
1 Entry to vim
2 Basics of vim
3 Vim motion
```

---

Here is a solution for the latter

The `*.mp4` files

```
lesson1.mp4
lesson2.mp4
lesson3.mp4
lesson4.mp4
lesson5.mp4
lesson6.mp4
lesson7.mp4
lesson8.mp4
lesson9.mp4
lesson10.mp4
lesson11.mp4
```

---

The individual text files:

```
1 Entry to vim
2 Basic of vim
3 Vim motion
4 Search and Replace vim
5 macros Vim
6 buffers vim
7 tabs vim
8 windows vim foo
9 insert vim
10 Vim global
11 help vim
```

---

The `bash` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=1
shopt -s nullglob
text_files=([1-9]*\ [Vv]im*)
shopt -u nullglob

while [[ -e "lesson$counter.mp4" ]]; do
  for i in "${!text_files[@]}"; do
    [[ -f "${text_files[i]}" ]] &&
    text_files_counter="${text_files[i]%% *}"
    (( counter == text_files_counter )) &&
    echo mv -v "lesson$((counter++)).mp4" "${text_files[i]}.mp4" &&
    unset -v 'text_files[i]'
  done
  text_files=("${text_files[@]}")
done
```

Output without the `echo`

```
renamed 'lesson1.mp4' -> '1 Entry to vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson2.mp4' -> '2 Basic of vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson3.mp4' -> '3 vim motion.mp4'
renamed 'lesson4.mp4' -> '4 Search and Replace vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson5.mp4' -> '5 macros vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson6.mp4' -> '6 buffers vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson7.mp4' -> '7 tabs vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson8.mp4' -> '8 windows vim foo.mp4'
renamed 'lesson9.mp4' -> '9 insert vim.mp4'
renamed 'lesson10.mp4' -> '10 vim global.mp4'
renamed 'lesson11.mp4' -> '11 help vim.mp4'
```